# Having trouble with sockets.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, rethinkdb

I'm having issues getting sockets to stream data to the client from my local rethinkdb server. I am fairly new to sockets.io so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Could someone please take a look at my code and help me out? Thanks

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var r = require('rethinkdb');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

r.connect({ db: "test" }).then(function(conn) {
    r.table('Articles').getField('title').run(conn)
    .then(function(cursor) {
            cursor.each(function(err, item) {
                console.log(item);
            io.sockets.emit("title", item);
        })
    })
})

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style media="screen">
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        socket.on("title", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#content').append($('<p>').text(data));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - what *does* happen? What errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing really. I don't get any errors but I also don't get any output

Comment: You're getting no console.log output in your Node terminal?

Comment: Nothing in the terminal.

Comment: Not even `listening on *:3000`?

Comment: Oh I'm getting listening on *:3000. I thought you meant the browser's console. The server appears to be running smoothly, even the database server. it returns my query ok but in the browser nothing is happening.

Comment: What about the `console.log(item);` bit? Does that show anything in the Node terminal?

Comment: Yes that bit is working.

Comment: Is `console.log(item);` firing *while* the browser is sitting there waiting for events? Or does the Rethink query go through all at once at the beginning and never fire again?

Comment: It fires at the beginning and when I start the server.

Comment: That's likely your issue, then. Socket.io is real-time. The browser has to be open and connected when the event is emitted. Given that you're emitting events before you even start the HTTP server, all the events are happening before the socket exists. Go back and start with a basic Socket.io tutorial and work up from there.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz. I was hoping there was a to populate the client with data initially and then run the realtime updates from the server afterwards. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sure. Your server needs to listen for on the `connection` event, which fires when a new socket is connected.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok that worked. Thanks! 
However, there's another issue, in the browser instead of a sensible output, I'm getting "[object undefined]". Could it have something to do with my syntax for displaying the output?